# How to make a IEnumerable method parallel method

Tags: c#, nested-loops, parallel-processing

[Following to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254780/is-it-possible-to-have-a-method-using-parallel-tasks-and-returns-ienumerablet), I want parallelize this method :

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllLogs(IEnumerable<IComputer> computers)
    {
        foreach (var cpt in computers)
        {
            foreach (var log in cpt.GetLogs())
            {
                yield return log;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the method "yield returns" a log when one of the method GetLogs is finished. If I have 4 computers which returns :

- Computer 01 : "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
- Computer 02 : "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
- Computer 03 : "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"
- Computer 04 : "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"

With the "sequential method", the output is :

```
a
b
c
d
e
1
2
3
4
5
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
I
II
III
IV
V
```

And the methods runs in 20 seconds. there is a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the `GetLogs` method.

I want the output looks like this :

```
III
a
4
gamma
b
c
IV
5
d
II
beta
e
1
2
delta
alpha
3
epsilon
I
```

and runs in few seconds.

I want to the methods returns an IEnumerable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllLogsParallel(IEnumerable<IComputer> computers)
{
    return computers
        .AsParallel()
        .SelectMany(cpt => cpt.GetLogs());
}
```

If you want to start processing of 4 `computer`-s at the same time you can adjust the degree of parallelism like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllLogsParallel(IEnumerable<IComputer> computers)
{
    return computers
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
        .SelectMany(cpt => cpt.GetLogs());
}
```

Following is a simplified explanation just for understanding.
To learn more about that just visit [PLINQ (Parallel LINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) at MSDN.

Well, `.AsParallel()` - splits the `computers` enumerable into 4 parts and starts 4 threads at the same time. Each thread executes `cpt.GetLogs()` for each `computer`. The result is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` - enumerable of enumerables. `SelectMany()` is used to flatten this list by concatenating inner enumerables and eliminating outer ones. Results are merged back automatically into the main thread in the order of their arrival.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine... All GetLogs() seems to finish in same time. (5 seconds env.) Yes I need explanations if possible :$

Comment: That's right, but they wait for each other before you get any result. ( As a little side note )

Comment: @FelixK. No they don't wait for each other.

Comment: @Florian Of course they do, not when executing the tasks, but the method returns all values at once and not with a behavior which is given by `yield`.

Comment: @FelixK. The return value of the method is an enumerable not the values returned by `GetLogs`. The method returns immediately. The values are queried and returned by enumerable as soon as you iterate it.

Comment: Good to know, i thought he parallizes the `GetLogs` and returns after everything is read.

Comment: it prints all at once. is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: printing at once is different behaviour from yield this example does not work. It is valid if you want the whole IEnumerable returned. Yield syntax implies returning one member at a time

Comment: You have to add [`.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withmergeoptions), otherwise the results of the query are buffered, and they are not flowing downstream immediately after they are produced.

Comment: Also be aware that this solution offers non-configurable backpressure. If the consumer of the query takes a lot of time to process a result before requesting the next one, eventually the `GetLogs` will stop being invoked after having accumulated (buffered) an arbitrary number of results. The producer will be suspended until the consumer requests a new result. You have no way to influence the size of the internal buffer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150533/parallel-ordered-consumable/75369673#75369673) for more nuances.