# For and Parallel For efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have question about difference of following code: 
 I will show the code first used with normal for loop.

Guesser class contructor starts mixing the character array and `startBruteForce` calls the function which permutates it in the key with the appropriate length that is matched to the private password. To every new key, I setted `Console.Write (key);`
And results was different in each loop.

```
DateTime timeStarted = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Start BruteForce - {0}", timeStarted.ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
                {
                    Guesser guesser = new Guesser();        
                    Thread thread = new Thread(guesser.startBruteForce);
                    thread.Start();
                }
                while (!Guesser.isMatched) ;
Console.WriteLine("Time passed: {0}s", DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeStarted).TotalSeconds);
```

and Parallel.For

```
DateTime timeStarted = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Start BruteForce - {0}", timeStarted.ToString());
                      Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount , (i) =>
                              {
                                  Guesser guesser = new Guesser();
                                  guesser.startBruteForce();
                             });
                        while (!Guesser.isMatched) ;        
    Console.WriteLine("Time passed: {0}s", DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeStarted).TotalSeconds);
```

In `ParallelFor` it was something like: `a,b,c,d,e,f...ab,ac,ad...`
While in normal foor loop it was much more permutated for ex: `b,r,1,a,k,b,ed`
It look like `ParrarelFor` created only one thread.

Normal for loop performs the brute-force algorithm faster than `Parallel.For` loop.

My question is why this is happening.

2. Another thing that interests me is why if I will narrow the number of iterations to `Environment.ProcessorCount/2`both algorithms execution time are faster than just iterted with unchanged`Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Comment: You're only running a loop with `Environment.ProcessorCount` elements. This is a fairly small value, so naturally `Parallel.For` will decide it's probably more efficient to use one thread for that. Turns out, that's not the case, but it can't open up your method to see what's inside. Your `Guesser` is suspect -- it takes no arguments at all, so it probably inappropriately relies on global state (if it's not just demonstration code). `Parallel.For` (and `Parallel.ForEach`) are designed to easily parallelize over large data sets, not to spawn a fixed, small set of workers.

Comment: What the heck is that `while` doing there. Also it is not easy to answer without knowing what `Guesser` does

Comment: We need to see the `Guesser`. I am guessing there is thread-unsafe code in there, or thread contention caused by inefficient locking.

Comment: Well the guesser contructor contains only shuffle method. Or do you want to see the whole class?

Comment: Τhe whole class!

Comment: Do you have HyperThreading turn on (default usually) in the BIOS. With HT if you have 4 cores, the OS thinks you have 8 cores and it will spawn 8 threads, which are all competing for 4 cores. Turn HT off and test again, and you will see the performance scale with the # of theads up to the # of cores you have.

Comment: PS. You get better time resolution by using the `Stopwatch` class, rather than `DateTime`.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8258406/380384

Comment: As far as serial code for permutations see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988082/380384) also. it is VB/NET but can be directly converted to C# and it works.